# How do you set the background to none on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to find how to set the background to none on windows 7. Not a solid color, but none. You can easily do it on XP.

The reason I want to do this is I use *xearth* to display the background. For it to display, there cannot be a different background displayed.

Comment: It may be that `xearth` is not compatible with Windows 7. The latest release was in 2006, before Windows Vista was public.

Comment: Possibly, but it would only work with XP when you set the background to none. I was hoping that you would be able to do that with windows 7, but I don't see an easy way to do that.

Comment: As I recall, setting the XP background to none simply made it a solid blue background

Comment: @Amazed:  With the default theme, yes, because that solid blue colour was the default.  I usually changed it to black, and I've found that users also sometimes changed it to match their desktop image for the background colour of text below each icon.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you are using, but this one works.

http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_xplanet/releases/?file_id=1958023

No need to change the background.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something. The interface is much nicer on xearth and it displays recent earthquakes, but at least this gives me something that works.